# Remove NSAttributedString Attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITextView` that upon initialization displays a string from a database and formats it using an `NSAttributedString`. This works fine. If the user clicks a 'New Entry' button, I need to clear the text view and allow the user to enter their own text. I do not want the attributes from the attributed string to follow along. (I just want an unformatted string). However, as soon as the user starts typing, their text is formatted like it was when it was displaying server data. I don't know how to reset this.

I've tried:

```
self.notes = @"";
self.notes = nil;
```

I thought that setting the field to `nil` would solve it for sure, but it doesn't. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Set the text view's [`typingAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/typingAttributes) property to an empty dictionary (or maybe `nil`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this to clear the Attributed feature

```
NSMutableAttributedString *originalMutableAttributedString = //users' string…
NSRange originalRange = NSMakeRange(0, originalMutableAttributedString.length);
[originalMutableAttributedString setAttributes:@{} range:originalRange];
textView.text = originalMutableAttributedString;
```